# Excel Macro : How to get notification when a VBA script stops execution

Tags: excel, vba, notifications

I am running a macro on a remote PC which executes every 5 seconds throughout the day.

Now I want that if something goes wrong and the macro stops execution I should be informed or notified via an Email.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handling.

```
Sub MySub()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Work done here...

    ' Screen for an expected error 
    If somethingWentWrong = True Then
        Err.Raise Number:=myErrorNumber, Source:="MySub", _
            Description:="This thing went wrong."
        ' Will now go to ErrorHandler
    End If

    ' More work done here...        

ExitProcedure:
    On Error Resume Next
    'Cleanup code goes here...
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    ' If an error occurs (anticipated or not), the following will be executed.
    Call SendEmailNotification( _
        Recipient:="you@there.com", _
        Subject:="Something went wrong.", _
        Message:=Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & Err.Source)
    ' Any other error handling goes here...
    Resume ExitProcedure
End Sub
```

To send an e-mail, there are various solutions out there. Search for CDO, [MAPI](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_vba_email_mapi.html), [Sockmail](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=109). Searching on those will give you examples for how to write your `SendEmailNotification` sub. Heads up: None of these are exactly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois Corbett. Thanks a lot..!! Keep up the good work and Keep helping people as you always do..!! :]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a mail send functionality within your error handling. If the machine the macro is being executed has Outlook properly set, I believe you can use [ActiveWorkbook.SendMail](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&checkda=1&ct=1301310427&rver=6.0.5276.0&wp=MCLBI&wlcxt=msdn%24msdn%24msdn&wreply=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203718%2528v=office.11%2529.aspx&lc=1033&cb=&id=254354).

If this PC doesn't have the Outlook set, you'll need to find out for a mail solution that fits your environment.

It would then looks like:

```
Sub MySub()

    On Error GoTo ProcError

    'Your stuff


ProcExit:

    Exit Sub

ProcError:

    ActiveWorkbook.SendMail "your.mail@yourdomain.com", "Application failed!"
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not clear how it will notify me when execution stops? Can you please explain exactly what your code does?

Comment: `SendMail` won't work for this, unfortunately. A security notification pops up and requires the user to click "Yes" before sending the e-mail. The notification won't be sent until you go to the machine and click "Yes", but then you don't need the notification anymore, do you...

Comment: @parth I've just exemplified an error handling that sends a mail when _something goes wrong and macro stops execution_, as per your comment. You need to adapt it into your system. It's more a concept explanation rather than a packaged solution.

Comment: Ok Tiago Cardoso. Thanks you :)

Comment: @Jean-François Corbet I never used this functionality. My code only shows the _idea_ of how the main problem could be solved, as he didn't provide any further information about his environment. I wouldn't bother adding a whole mail sending functionality if he could use the embedded ActiveWorkbook.SendMail. Besides, if he chooses this path, he could dig a little bit to find ways to avoid it or find another solutions for mail sending. Either way, I believe we need to offer a overview of the solution, since we have an overview of his environment.